# TFVC is not showing pending changes through cmd

Tags: jenkins, tfs, tfvc

```
tf stat
tf checkin /comment:"Test From Command Line" /recursive /noprompt
```

Above command is neither checking in nor showing pending changes

Comment: What *is* it showing? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It was showing - there are no pending changes.
But I found the ans

Answer (score 0):

> TFS is not showing pending changes through cmd

You should run "`tf add`" command to add these files into Pending Changes before run "`tf checkin`" command:

```
tf add * /recursive
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer-
Need to run below before checkin through CMD
tf checkout [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/recursive] [/encoding:encoding] itemspec [/login: username,[password]]

[Refer this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command?view=azure-devops)